# How to find all the records having unicode character in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I know there are other similar questions but they are specific to certain special characters.
I am looking for a solution by which i can filter out all the records having unicode character in a column in DB2

Comment: Define "unicode character". In a Unicode database any stored character is a Unicode character, so by that definition all records with non-null values would have Unicode characters in them.

Answer (score 0):

As mustaccio said, all chars are unicode.

Probably, you are having problems when using text characters from other languages. It is very common that native-english speakers do not understand the problem of other characters, because the 26 character are standard in all encodings.

If you are having that problem, you have to formulate your problem in another way. Something like:

> Taking all unicode characters as a set, I would like to know which characters fall outside the subset of the valid letters in my language (spanish in my case).

With this in mind, you can query your data, and perform an analysis of which values are not part of your language. You can do that with a regular expression.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ENCODING_VALIDATION_SPANISH (
 IN TEXT VARCHAR(256) 
) RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
LANGUAGE SQL
PARAMETER CCSID UNICODE
SPECIFIC F_ENC_VAL_SP
DETERMINISTIC
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
READS SQL DATA
F_ENC_VAL_SP: BEGIN
  DECLARE RET VARCHAR(32);
  SET RET = XMLCAST (
    -- The next line define the valid characters for the Spanish language.
    XMLQUERY ('fn:matches($TEXT,"^[A-Za-z\- \.,\?\u00C1\u00E1\u00C9\u00E9\u00CD\u00ED\u00D3\u00F3\u00DA\u00FA\u00DC\u00EC\u0147\u0148]*$")' 
      PASSING TEXT AS "TEXT"
  ) AS VARCHAR(32));
  RETURN RET;
END F_ENC_VAL_SP @
```

I wrote an article, where I explain that problem: http://angocadb2.blogspot.fr/2013/09/validate-encoding-problems-in-db2.html